# map_dbl not found when clustening using silhouette method

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset that I want to cluster using the silhouette method, but when I get to line "avg_sil_values <- map_dbl(k.values, avg_sil)" I get the error: map_dbl not found. I have installed tidyverse and have also installed just purrr, but I am still getting the same error. [image: sample data]

What can I do?

```
avg_sil <- function(k) {km.res <- kmeans(country_norm_ok, centers = k, nstart = 25)
s <- silhouette(km.res$cluster, dist(df))
mean(ss[, 3])}
k.values <- 2:15
avg_sil_values <- map_dbl(k.values, avg_sil)
plot(k.values, avg_sil_values, type = "b", pch = 19, frame = FALSE, xlab = "Number of clusters K", ylab = "Average Silhouettes")
```

updated:

```
> avg_sil <- function(k) {km.res <- kmeans(country_norm_ok, centers = k, nstart = 25)
+ s <- silhouette(km.res$cluster, dist(df))
+ mean(ss[, 3])}
> k.values <- 2:15
> avg_sil_values <- map_dbl(k.values, avg_sil)
Error in silhouette(km.res$cluster, dist(df)) : 
  no se pudo encontrar la función "silhouette"
Called from: .f(.x[[i]], ...)
Browse[1]> plot(k.values, avg_sil_values, type = "b", pch = 19, frame = FALSE, xlab = "Number of clusters K", ylab = "Average Silhouettes")
Error durante el wrapup: objeto 'avg_sil_values' no encontrado
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Browse[1]> function(k) {km.res <- kmeans(country_norm_ok, centers = k, nstart = 25)
+ s <- silhouette(km.res$cluster, dist(df))
+ mean(ss[, 3])}
function(k) {km.res <- kmeans(country_norm_ok, centers = k, nstart = 25)
s <- silhouette(km.res$cluster, dist(df))
mean(ss[, 3])}
<environment: 0x7f8429fa8f88>
Browse[1]>
```

Comment: As well as installing the packages, have you called `library(tidyverse)` or `library(purrr)` before running your code?

Comment: ah! I forgot, I did now and got a different error, I will edit the question and add it :)

Comment: Does a simple mapping work? `map_dbl(mtcars, sum)`. Now I see your edit, are you loading the library that contains the `silhouette()` function?

Comment: I loaded the library cluster